# How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery:Error href is null

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to get to the default home link(href) on my sharepoint site using jquery but i keep getting href is undefined.
I would like to change it to another URL
I have tried

```
alert($(".static selected menu-item")[0].href).text();



<div class="s4-lp s4-toplinks">
        <div class="s4-tn" id="zz17_TopNavigationMenuV4">
            <div class="menu horizontal menu-horizontal">
                <ul class="root static">
                    <li class="static selected">
                    <a accesskey="1" href="/sites/Home" class="static selected menu-item" style="height: 11px; margin-top: 0px;">
                    <span class="additional-background">
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Home</span>
                    <span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span></span></a>
                    </li>
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay close attention to your selector. Class names must start with a dot (`.`), whereas tag names do not.

Your selector reads:

```
$(".static selected menu-item")
```

Which means "a `menu-item` element that is inside an element of type `selected` that is inside an element *with a class* of `static`.

From your markup, it is unclear what the correct selector is. If you want to select an anchor tag with all three classes, use this:

```
$(".static.selected.menu-item")
```

If you want to select an element with the class `menu-item` inside an element with a class of `selected`, inside an element with the class `static`, use this:

```
$(".static .selected .menu-item")
```

Answer (score 1):

`alert()` does not have a `text()` method.

Try...

```
$('.static .selected .menu-item').attr('href', 'new_href');
```

Comment: Hi Alex,
      i changed the code to change the url but it didint work :(
Should the href be the actual url i want to change? e.g i did
attr('/sites/Home/','/sites/newHome/')

Comment: Thx Alex fixed it...I reckon i need some sleep:)

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
alert($(".static selected menu-item")[0].href).text();
```

to this:

```
alert($(".static .selected .menu-item").attr('href'));
```